# What's the word for every "message" in a dialogue?

Tags: word-request

> A: Hi, Bob
>   B: Hi, how are you?
>   A: I'm great, you?
>   ...

Each one of these lines forms a spoken dialogue. What is each of these "messages" called? *Message* seems correct, but makes me think of a written dialogue. Is there a better word?

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a play, I'd go with "**lines**", just like you already used. -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/line)

> (noun) 3.2 ***lines*** The words of an actor's part in a play or film.
>
> *he couldn't seem to remember his lines and had to read his dialogue off boards.*
>
> *But, the moment she began speaking her lines, everyone was as in awe of her as I had been at auditions.*

Comment: There's also a term "**conversational line**"

Answer (score 2):

In linguistics, what you are describing is called a ***turn***. Here are some sample texts in which this term is used:

“[Utterance Units in Spoken Dialogue](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fea1/db9cfef52cfbc400bb974e1eb60c06fdc712.pdf)”, Traum and Heeman

“[Turn construction unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_construction_unit)” at *Wikipedia*

“[Utterance](http://www.glossary.sil.org/term/utterance)” in the “Glossary of Linguistic Terms” by SIL International

Answer (score 0):

How about **statement**?

> - a definite or clear expression of something in speech or writing.

(google)

In your example, A states something, then B states something, then A states something else. It's a series of statements.

"Line" was pretty good, too.